I want to make an condition on dates with window functions
I'm trying to calculate the difference between two events where the condition X is happening and I also have the condition that if the events happens in the same day, the second event will take the previous date not the one earlier on that same date. (Does it make sense ?)
I found a way to do it with a subquery but it's taking so much time, this is why I want to know if there is another way to do it.
(
    SELECT MAX(ld2.date)
    FROM table ld2
    WHERE  ld2.condition = 'X'
    AND ld2.id = ld.id
    AND ld2.date < ld.date
) AS last_date,

So I tried using a MAX function and I want to apply this condition to my window function :
MAX(CASE WHEN condition = 'X' AND date < LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) THEN date END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS last_date

I tried a lead function but i've got the error : may not be nested inside another window function.
I'm working with snowflake, does anyone have an idea of how I can do that?

Please create a minimal reproducible example

For the NEST functions problem, make a sub-select thus something like select a.*, max(a.y) from (select b.*, LEAD(b.z) over (.....) as y from table_name as b) as a) type thing

-- using row_num to order the rows, but date could equally have a time component.

with data(row_num, id, date, condition) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 1, '2024-09-25', 'X'),
    (2, 2, '2024-09-25', 'X'),
    (3, 2, '2024-09-26', 'X'),
    (4, 3, '2024-09-25', 'X'),
    (5, 3, '2024-09-26', 'X'),
    (6, 3, '2024-09-26', 'X') -- these both want to use row 4
)
select d.*
    ,lead(d.date) over (partition by d.id order by d.date, d.row_num) as next_date
    ,iff(next_date = d.date, null, d.date) as not_today
from data as d
where d.condition = 'X'
order by d.row_num;


this gives us an edge when the NOT_TODAY is only present for the last of each day.
Now we can run a LAG that skips nulls over that edge.
select d.*
    ,lead(d.date) over (partition by d.id order by d.date, d.row_num) as next_date
    ,iff(next_date = d.date, null, d.date) as not_today
    ,lag(not_today) ignore nulls over (partition by d.id order by d.date, d.row_num) as prior_date
from data as d
where d.condition = 'X'
order by d.row_num;

but this makes the error:

Window function [LEAD(D.DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY D.ID ORDER BY D.DATE ASC NULLS LAST, D.ROW_NUM ASC NULLS LAST)]
may not be nested inside another window function.

so we layer the selects:
with data(row_num, id, date, condition) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 1, '2024-09-25', 'X'),
    (2, 2, '2024-09-25', 'X'),
    (3, 2, '2024-09-26', 'X'),
    (4, 3, '2024-09-25', 'X'),
    (5, 3, '2024-09-26', 'X'),
    (6, 3, '2024-09-26', 'X') -- these both want to use row 4
)
select *
    ,lag(not_today) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by date, row_num) as prior_date
    ,datediff('days', prior_date, date) as days_gap
from (
    select d.*
        ,lead(d.date) over (partition by d.id order by d.date, d.row_num) as next_date
        ,iff(next_date = d.date, null, d.date) as not_today   
    from data as d
    where d.condition = 'X'
)
order by row_num;


After Comment Update:
if you just want to keep the rows that have the "last of the day" edge, that can be changed to use a qualify to filter the non-wanted rows out in the sub-select:
with data(row_num, id, date, condition) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 1, '2024-09-25', 'X'),
    (2, 2, '2024-09-25', 'X'),
    (3, 2, '2024-09-26', 'X'),
    (4, 3, '2024-09-25', 'X'),
    (5, 3, '2024-09-26', 'X'),
    (6, 3, '2024-09-26', 'X') 
)
select * 
from data
qualify row_number() over(partition by id, date order by row_num desc) = 1


Thus the date diff being done is a serperate select becomes:
with data(row_num, id, date, condition) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 1, '2024-09-25', 'X'),
    (2, 2, '2024-09-25', 'X'),
    (3, 2, '2024-09-26', 'X'),
    (4, 3, '2024-09-25', 'X'),
    (5, 3, '2024-09-26', 'X'),
    (6, 3, '2024-09-26', 'X') 
)
select 
    *,
    datediff('days', lag(date) over (partition by id order by date), date) as days_diff
from (
    select 
        * 
    from data
    qualify row_number() over(partition by id, date order by row_num desc) = 1
)
order by 1;

giving:


ID|EVENT_DATE|EVENT_CODE|LAST_01EVENT_DATE| --+----------+--------------+---------------+  123|2020-01-01|             01|NULL   |    123|2020-06-01|             03|2020-01-01|  123|2021-02-01|             01|2020-01-01 |  123|2021-02-01|             01|2020-01-01|
I only want to keep the date of the last event with the code 01 (ignoring the rest) and en edge case in this is that, if the same client made the event 01 in the same day (2021-02-01) , for the second event that same day I want it's LAST_01EVENT_DATE to be 2020-01-01 and not the one earlier that same date.
